# Maven 3.6.3 archetype:generate не работает с openjdk 14.0.1

Tags: maven, openjdk

Все переменные среды установлены правильно, скачал мавен, скачал openjdk 14.0.1, запускаю, mvn -v работает, java -version работает, однако при попытке создать проект мавен через mvn archetype:generate выбрасывается FileNotFoundException (tzdb.dat)

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, правильное ли это решение, но возможно у кого то такая же проблема и это ему поможет:
Я просто скачал openjdk версии 13.0.2, и в нем есть файл tzdb.dat, и maven без ошибок работает с этим jdk
P.S. вероятно, в openjdk 14.0.1 отсутствуют еще какие-либо файлы поэтому простое копирование tzdb.dat из 13.0.2 в 14.0.1 я не делал